# Extreme server load

Tags: mysql, indexing, server, load, cardinality

I am using a vps server and I run a joomla 3.6.0 site with k2 cck. For searching my k2 items I use the Ja k2 filter component. I tried to communicate with the programmers of the component but with no luck.

When I have the default settings of the search results page (ascending) everything works great, but I want the descending setting in my results page, so when I configure the component in such way, then all my problems starts. I have an extreme server overload and I have to restart the apache or the mysql to be in normal again until next time.

Here are some screenshots of my mysql database.

[image: structure of k2]

[image: indexes of k2]

Any ideas about indexes and cardinality for better performance?
I don't know much about mysql because I am a multimedia developer. So, I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

Plan A:  Don't call it "fulltext"

Plan B:  Put backtics around it:  `fulltext`

Plan C:  Don't use a 3rd party software package that fails to help you with issues like this.

We can't judge the indexes without seeing the `SELECT`.